# appfog gem install — command not found

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems, appfog

I have a Rails app that I want to upload to AppFog. Installed the command line tool with `gem install af` successfully but when I want to execute it gives me the error:

```
~$ af login
-bash: af: command not found
```

So I went to my rbenv directory and it's there:

```
~$ cd .rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/
af-0.3.18.7/
```

Is this a path problem? How do I fix this?

---

Environment:

- OSX Mountain Lion
- rbenv + ruby 1.93 p194
- rubygems 1.8.24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that restarting my OS (or maybe it's the terminal?) solved this problem.

Comment: So weird. I restarted terminal and voila!

Answer (score 1):

I just had to install the af gem as sudo

I ran:

```
sudo gem install af
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run the command ***af*** from the path?

> cd *.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/af-0.3.18.7/bin*
>
> af *login*

If yes, then you need to include this sort of path in something like your profile (similar to .bashrc in Ubuntu) in Mac so that you run from anywhere in terminal.